# payflow Link silent post not working with refund

Tags: paypal

Does PayFlow link silent post works with refund ?

I have configured silent post in Paypal manager settings. It is working fine with checkout (sale).

When I am making a refund request to pay-flow Link, the response is being redirected to main web site instead of redirecting to configured silent post URL.

Is there any way I can redirect refund request to the configured URL ?

Answer (score 0):

No the silent post is not applicable to refunds . It only applies to the one time payment done via the hosted checkout pages .

And at the same time, for refunds you don't even have to do any redirection. It's a one step process where you will send the post data to the PayPal to do the refund .